# Include require.js library in bundle or keep separate?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, amd

When combining AMD modules with RequireJS and the r.js optimizer, is it better to bundle the require.js library with your modules or keep it separate?

Comment: Since you are optimizing, probably best to use [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) rather than the full require library. See [the require optimization FAQ](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-optimization.html#wrap).

Comment: i used to keep it separate, as it loader tool and may be replaced with other one. However, building separate libs bundle, like (jquery + requirejs + underscore) also looks like a good approach as it pretty static and rarely updates.

Comment: @steveax: thanks for responding; my app is multi-page otherwise I'd definitely implement your suggestion.

Comment: @Evgeniy: After researching further I definitely agree with you. Feel free to post an answer if you'd like the points.

Comment: Whoever voted to close should reconsider, and if it's a mod, IMO his/her status should be reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can follow: use require library separatly as module loader lib may be replaced with other. Second build separate bundle file with tools, frameworks and libs used on majority of pages. INHO second approach is best practice to follow as there is not huge number of requirejs alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This [recent comment](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/11/18/a-require-dot-js-multipage-shimmed-site-how-to/#comment-1138638164) from [Rob Dodson](http://robdodson.me/) in his definitive post [A Require.js Multi-page Shimmed Site: How-To](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/11/18/a-require-dot-js-multipage-shimmed-site-how-to/#comment-1138638164) convinced me that bundling require.js is the best way to go. I'm surprised this approach hasn't been discussed more widely; it seems like a no-brainer to avoid the additional HTTP request.

> "It would probably also be a good idea to compile require.js into the
>   common.js lib since every page will need both. You just have to make
>   sure require.js is at the top of the file."